# i have a sequence of list with 1 and 0 and i would like output in this format where sub lists are created until zero is met

Tags: python

This is the input and the output should be as shown. This is what i have tried:

```
input a = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
output a = [[1,1,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,0],[1,1,0]]
def new_list(x):
    new = []
    for item in range(length(x)):
        if  x[item]== 0:
            new.append(x[:item+1])
    return new
```

Comment: "This is what i have tried:" - and what was the result? Please post codes which does not result in an error (`NameError: name 'length' is not defined`)

Answer (score 0):

First extract to inides of `0` elements. Then use it to slice the original list:

```py
a = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
def new_list(x):
    indices = [i for i,e in enumerate(x) if e == 0] # indices of zeros
    indices = [0] + [i+1 for i in indices] # 0 is 1st slice, +1 is for slicing (1 higher than index)
    ii1,ii2 = indices[:-1],indices[1:] # first and second index for each sub-list
    return [x[i1:i2] for i1,i2 in zip(ii1,ii2)]
print(new_list(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Few modifications in your function to get your required output.

```
def new_list(x):
    new = []
    slice_idx = 0
    for index, val in enumerate(x):
        if val == 0:
            new.append(x[slice_idx:index+1])
            slice_idx = index +1
    return new
```

Input: `a = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]`

```
new_list(a)
```

> [[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]